# Get the number of rows affected by multiple delete

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I get a count of the number of affected rows when I'm deleting multiple rows in PDO?  This is the technique I'm using to delete multiple rows:

```
$selected = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $N = count($selected);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
        $result = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE id= :id');
        $result->bindParam(':id', $selected[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->execute();
    }
```

I tried this, but it always returned 1:

```
$deleted = $result->rowCount();
    if ($deleted) {
        echo $deleted.' was deleted.';
    }
```

Comment: yes it work delete couple of rows. am i put it in wrong scope? i was put it outside the loop after For.

Comment: your running a loop, so each call is deleting 1, you need to add a counter

Comment: would you show me how to implement the counter?

Comment: full answer below. comment on it if you have any more questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running a loop, so each call is deleting 1; you need to add a counter.

So add:

```
 $deleted += $result->rowCount();
```

inside the loop

and then outside:

```
if ($deleted) {
        echo $deleted.' was deleted.';
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the id field is unique, then that statement could affect at most 1 row. However you are preparing a new statement and executing it in a loop. You should try adding up how many you delete.

```
$deleted = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
    $result = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE id= :id');
    $result->bindParam(':id', $selected[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->execute();
    $deleted = $deleted + $result->rowCount();
}
echo $deleted.' was deleted.';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it work too but Dagon is the first who answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it in 1 delete instead of running multiple deletes.
This way rowCount() will show the actual results deleted.

```
$selected = $_POST['checkbox'];

$placeholder = array();
$values = array();

foreach ($selected as $id) {
  $placeholder[] = ":".$id;
  $values[":".$id] = $id;
}


$sql = "Delete FROM users WHERE id IN (".implode(', ',$placeholder).") ";
$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result->execute($values);

$deleted = $result->rowCount();

if ($deleted>0) {
    echo $deleted.' was deleted.';
}
```